# solving system of ODE until equilibrium in Matlab

Tags: matlab, numerical-methods, ode

I am trying to explore the equilibrium of a system of ODEs when tweaking different parameters. Currently, I have my ODE function (see SB1ode, below) and a function that calls the solver while passing the set of parameter values (SB1, below).
I need help on how to tell the solver to stop at equilibrium, please, rather than at a fixed time.
Thanks!

```
function [t,N] = SI1(s0,i0,Tmax,b,d,<more parameters>)

% Initial conditions
y0 = [s0 i0];

% parameters
P(1) = b;      
P(2) = d;      
P(3) = ... etc

% time steps
time = [0 Tmax];

% solve ODE system
[t,N] = ode45(@(t,Y) SI1ode(t,Y,P), time, y0);

end


function Y = SI1ode(t,x,P)

%parameters
b = P(1);      
d = P(2);      
...etc

%State variables
S = x(1);
I = x(2);

Y(1) = equation 1;
Y(2) = equation 2;
Y=Y';   %make column vector
end
```

And my running script is:

```
Tmax = 100;
s0 = 100;
i0 = 1e-2;

b = 2;      
...etc

D = [0 .01 0.05 0.1 0.15 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 .6 .7 .8 .9 1];

for j=1:length(D)

    d = D(j);
    [t,N] = SI1(s0,i0,Tmax,b,d,<more parameters>);
    result(j) = N(end,2)/(N(end,1)+N(end,2));

end
```

Comment: I understand from the documentation that this involves event handling, but I am getting confused with the specific implementation here..

Answer (score 1):

The integration can be interrupted by using an output function or an event. If you prefer an event you should write something like `if equilibrium, isterminal(1)=1; end`, while in the case of an output function the code would become `if equilibrium, status=1; end`.

Regarding how to test for the equilibrium condition you should compare the previous values of the solution with the current ones, an operation that can be done component by component or with a norm criteria. In both cases this is like computing the derivative of the solution by finite differences.

This operation imply that you must have access to the solution computed at the previous time steps. You can use the output function to save these values in a global variable.